# Find $\min \sum |a_n|$ when $\sum |a_n|^2 = 1$ and $\sum |a_n|^4 = \lambda$ (Katznelson's Ex $4.1.2.$)

Tags: optimization, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

This is Exercise $4.1.2.$ in Katznelson's *An Introduction to Harmonic Analysis*.

> Let $\{a_n\}_{n\in \Bbb Z}$ be a sequence of numbers and $\lambda > 0$. Find $\min \sum_{n\in \Bbb Z} |a_n|$ under the conditions $\sum_{n\in \Bbb Z} |a_n|^2 = 1$ and $\sum_{n\in \Bbb Z} |a_n|^4 = \lambda$.

This optimization problem seems to have no apparent connection with Fourier Analysis, and I'm just looking for a hint to get started. Of course, I've thought about $\{a_n\}$ being the Fourier coefficients of some function $f\in L^2(\Bbb T)$, i.e., $\widehat f(n) = a_n$ for all $n\in \Bbb Z$, $\|f\|_2 = \sum_{n\in \Bbb Z} |a_n|^2 = 1$, and $\sum_{n\in \Bbb Z} |\widehat f(n)|^4 = \lambda$. I'm stuck here.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe useful hint: consider the interpolation of $\ell^p$ spaces, i.e., $$\|a\|_{\ell^2}\leq \|a\|_{\ell^1}^{1/3}\|a\|_{\ell^4}^{2/3}.$$

Comment: Try Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: @Mason That's not harmonic analysis! Also, there are infinitely many variables.

Comment: @stoic-santiago Lagrange multipliers is true for Banach spaces. That would be the first thing I try.

Comment: @Feng I like your approach. Could you provide some more details? I'm not sure how you got the interpolation inequality, though I believe it must be similar to the setting of $L^p$ spaces. Besides, we'd like the inequality to be sharp if we want to find the minimum.

Comment: @stoic-santiago Thanks for your kind appreciation. The interpolation inequality follows from the discrete Holder’s inequality. I will write an answer later after today’s class.

Comment: @stoic-santiago I'm very sorry. After some trial, I only get some partial results. See my answer below. I will be keep thinking about the remaining parts.

Comment: @stoic-santiago From lagrange multipliers you can deduce that the minimizer has only finitely many nonzero components, so it suffices to solve the problem for $(a_1, \dots, a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $a_i > 0$ for all $i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Partial answer.** In this answer, we prove the following three things:
$$0<\lambda\leq 1,\tag{1}$$
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}|a_n|\geq \lambda^{-1/2},\tag{2}$$
and
$$\text{the inequality $(2)$ is sharp for }  \lambda\in\Lambda:=\left\{\frac1k:k=1,2,3,\cdots\right\}.\tag{3}$$

*Proof of $(1)$.* Since $\sum_{n\in \Bbb Z} |a_n|^2 = 1$, we have $|a_n|\in[0,1]$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$, hence $|a_n|^4\leq|a_n|^2$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$ and then $\lambda=\sum_{n\in \Bbb Z} |a_n|^4\leq \sum_{n\in \Bbb Z} |a_n|^2 = 1$.

*Proof of $(2)$.* It follows from [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Counting_measure) that
\begin{align*}
1=\sum_{n\in \Bbb Z} |a_n|^2&=\sum_{n\in \Bbb Z} |a_n|^{\frac23}|a_n|^{\frac43}\leq \left(\sum_{n\in \Bbb Z}|a_n|^{\frac23\cdot\frac32}\right)^{\frac23}\left(\sum_{n\in \Bbb Z}|a_n|^{\frac43\cdot3}\right)^{\frac13}\\
&=\left(\sum_{n\in \Bbb Z}|a_n|\right)^{\frac23}\left(\sum_{n\in \Bbb Z}|a_n|^{4}\right)^{\frac13}=\left(\sum_{n\in \Bbb Z}|a_n|\right)^{\frac23}\lambda^{\frac13},
\end{align*}
hence $(2)$ holds.

*Proof of $(3)$.* If $\lambda=\frac1k$ for some $k\in\mathbb N_{\geq1}$, we consider the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ defined by
$$a_n=\begin{cases} \sqrt\lambda, & 1\leq n\leq k,\\ 0, & \text{otherwise};\end{cases}$$
then
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}|a_n|^2=k\lambda=1,\qquad \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}|a_n|^4=k\lambda^2=\lambda,$$
and $\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}|a_n|=k\sqrt\lambda=\lambda^{-1/2}$.

**I don't know if $(2)$ is sharp for $\lambda\in(0,1]\setminus\Lambda$.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll also think about the remaining parts.